# SASS fade_in effect problems to watch

Tags: css, sass, fade

I am trying to get a differents divs with gradients color, from darker to lighter.

I can watch how my code edit lighter the color, but i can't watch the darker effect. I review the code and all are working correctly. The fade_out effect is working, but not the fade_in effect - at it is identical. When I review the css file generated, i watch that the background-color are the same that the $color-base value. Why the fade_in effect is not appreciating?

SCSS:

```
    @if $k==1 {
        $color-base: red;
    }
    @else if $k==2 {
        $color-base: blue;
    }
    @else {
        $color-base: green;
    }
    .container-#{$k} {
        .base-color {
            background-color: $color-base;
        }
        @for $i from 4 through 1 {
            .darken-#{$i} {
                background-color: fade_in($color-base, 0.2 * $i);
                .color-box-text {
                    color: red;
                }
            }
            .lighten-#{$i} {
                background-color: fade_out($color-base, 0.2 * $i);
                .color-box-text {
                    color: black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

> 

```
    <div class="box darken-4"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 4</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-3"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 3</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-2"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 2</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-1"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 1</span></div>
    <div class="box base-color"><span class="color-box-text">Base color</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-1"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 1</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-2"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 2</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-3"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 3</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-4"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="mycontainer container-2">
    <div class="box darken-4"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 4</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-3"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 3</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-2"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 2</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-1"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 1</span></div>
    <div class="box base-color"><span class="color-box-text">Base color</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-1"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 1</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-2"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 2</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-3"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 3</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-4"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="mycontainer container-3">
    <div class="box darken-4"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 4</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-3"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 3</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-2"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 2</span></div>
    <div class="box darken-1"><span class="color-box-text">Darken 1</span></div>
    <div class="box base-color"><span class="color-box-text">Base color</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-1"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 1</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-2"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 2</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-3"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 3</span></div>
    <div class="box lighten-4"><span class="color-box-text">Lighten 4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your `fade_in` and `fade_out` functions as well, your code is incomplete.

Comment: With SASS you don't need functions to fade_in and fade_out color effect. With this code, the fade_out color effect runs correctly, but the fade_in color effect not

Comment: Hum, you're right. In the doc the only functions I could find are named `fade-in` and `fade-out` so I asumed yours were custom.

Comment: Yes, i learned with fade_in and fade_out, but in the doc, they appear like `fade-in` and `fade-out`. Anyway, both `fade-out` and `fade_out` are running with their correct syntax, but the result with `fade-in` and `fade_in` is not showing. If i check the styles in the browser, the color assigned is still like the $color-base value.

Comment: I found the problem, I will write an answer.

Comment: You don't need SASS nested functions to get a fade in out effect. You can use simple css animation with keyframes. You will then also not need the 20 lines of HTML in the container.

Comment: @lortschi obviously I know that, but i needed to do it with SASS. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fade-in()` is doing the same as `opacify()` and according to the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#opacify):

> The `opacify()` function increases the alpha channel by a fixed amount.

Your `$color-base` values are all opaque and therefore the `fade-in()` function doesn't apply since their alpha channels have already the max value. If you try with a base color with an alpha value lower than `1` you will see that your code works fine.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason i didn't watch any change. Thanks!